# Create a Scroll Event with add Event Listener - Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, scroll, addeventlistener

I'm trying to achieve something in vanilla JS and it's not playing ball.  I have an element I want to change color after a certain scroll length, but when I use addEventListener('scroll', function) etc it's not working, but I'm not getting any errors in my console.
Any help would be awesome.

Emily

The code is below and I have a pen here: https://codepen.io/emilychews/pen/eRYwzm

HTML

```
<div class="box"></div>
```

CSS

```
body {height: 200vh;}

.box {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: red;
}
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
var box = document.getElementsByClassName('box')[0];

window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {

  if (box.scrollTop > 0) {
    box.style.background = "blue";
  }

});
```

Comment: That's because `box.scrollTop` always returns `0`. Add `console.log(box.scrollTop);` above your `if()` statement and you will see the result of `box.scrollTop` in the console.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to get the `scrollTop` on the document `body` element, not on your box. In your case, `box.scrollTop` will always be `0`.

Replace this:

```
  if (box.scrollTop > 0) {
    box.style.background = "blue";
  }
```

with this:

```
  if (document.body.scrollTop > 0) {
    box.style.background = "blue";
  }
```

Also note, that as of now it's better to use **window.pageYOffset** as `document.body.scrollTop` is deprecated in *strict mode*. [Read this](http://blog.grayghostvisuals.com/js/detecting-scroll-position/) to learn more about scroll detection on the entire window.

Demo: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/mwdZwL